# Wrong number of file count being returned from directory

Tags: c#

I have a method which searches the top directory for any files and returns the count which is as follows:

```
public int AttachmentCountItemDirectory(string directoryPath)
{
   int fileCount = 0;
   if (Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
       fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;

   return fileCount;
}
```

The above method works great when there's 1 or more files in the directory. The issue I am facing is when there are no files the count is still **1** for some weird reason. I have enabled **Show Hidden files, folders, and drives** and from the image below it's clear there is no file.

[image: Directory Image]

[image]

Am I missing something obvious here? Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please

Comment: Well have you looked at what the file that's being returned is? Just call `Directory.GetFiles` in one statement, store the result in a variable, and return the length of the array later - that way you can look at the content of the result, not just the length.

Comment: Show protected operating system files as well. Probably thumbs.db or something.

Comment: It could be some kind of system file. Like `thumbs.db` or `..`

Comment: You want to return the attachment-count. So specify the appropriate filter instead of using `"*"`

Comment: @TimSchmelter can I supply multiple filters at once?

Comment: Can also be `desktop.ini` if you customized the folder's properties.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I will take that route

Comment: @Equalsk It was thumbs.db

Comment: @code: you could use LINQ, but what filters you want to apply?

Comment: why not use DirectoryInfo?  Less work than GetFiles()

Comment: @TimSchmelter The filters I want to apply are, `pdf,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,jpeg,png,`

Comment: @Rob Can you provide an example please

Comment: no don't use linq, it'll be a complete pig if the number of files is large.

Comment: take a look at www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/99aadd/working-with-the-directoryinfo-class-in-C-Sharp/ to get you started.  (on purpose provided as text link so you know I'm not trying to lead you to a scam site.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You commented

> It was thumbs.db

So the original question is answered.

My suggestion was to apply a filter to return only relevant files

> Can i supply multiple filters at once? The filters I want to apply
>   are: pdf,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,jpeg,png

Yes, you can use LINQ:

```
public int AttachmentCountItemDirectory(string directoryPath)
{
   string[] attExt = {".pdf",".doc",".docx",".xls",".xlsx",".jpeg",".png"};
   return Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath)
     .Count(f => attExt.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

I would not return 0 if an invalid path is passed to the method. I throw an exception then.